# How to define gallery responsive image size in grid

Tags: html, css

All 12 of the li img inside of .gallery displays correctly in codepen.io but when brought into jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/n61y2acv/ it breaks and displays past .gallery width. Why does this occur?

```
.gallery {
 display: grid;
 grid-gap: 0.75rem;
 grid-auto-flow: dense;
 padding: 40px;
 list-style: none;
 background: white;
 width: 100%;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 margin-top: 0;
 margin-bottom: 0;

  li  {
   figure, img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    border-radius:15px;
    display: block;
    object-fit: cover;
   }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Give max-width to your image element!

```css
img {
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, however there is still a gap between the right side of .gallery and the edge of the browser?

Comment: Can you give a screenshot so that I can check